# netaxept payment integration in interspire throw Refused by issuer Exception

Tags: soap-client, interspire-shopping-cart, netaxept

i am integrating [netaxept](http://www.betalingsterminal.no/Netthandel-forside/Teknisk-veiledning/Overview/)  payment gateway in interspire shopping cart but its throwing exception "Refused by issuer" each time i try to porocess the folling line

```
$OutputParametersOfProcess = $client->__call('Process', array("parameters" => $InputParametersOfProcess));
```

this is working in sample code but not working for me the only difference i have notice that tha  SoapClient sdl Resource id #10 with the sample code and for me is 68 or 69 
i am unable to figure out the problem either with SoapClient  library or with the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

There should be more info in the return value. Refused by issuer really means that the bank declined your payment.